# I wanna Import Video files dynamically, by props passed down by another component

Tags: reactjs, import

**I Have listed some lesson'(s), videos the videos will be played in a modal**

```js
<div className="list_lessons">
    <ul>
         { lesson.lessonFile && lesson.lessonFile.length > 0 && lesson.lessonFile.map((file, i) => (
           <li key={i}> 
              <p data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" className="video" onClick={<Modal videolink={file.filepath} />}>
              { file.filename }
              </p>
          </li> ))} 
    </ul>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here I have passed the file path to the modal component as (  )

this is the modal part =>

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom'
import Videoplayer from 'react-video-js-player'
import videoSrc from '../FILES/1. Introduction.mp4';

const Modal = ({ vidPoster, videoName }) => {


    const poster = !vidPoster ? 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1602526215099-19d4d14797d6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80' : vidPoster


    return createPortal(
      <Fragment>
        <div
          
          className="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg"
          tabIndex={-1}
          role="dialog"
          aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
          aria-hidden="true">

          <div style={{width: "100%"}} className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">

            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
                  Modal title
                </h5>
                
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="close"
                  data-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close"
                  >
                  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
              </div>

              <div className="modal-body">
                {!videolink && (
                  <Fragment>
                    <h5 className="modal-title" style={{display: 'block'}} id="exampleModalLongTitle1">
                      Playing Default Video...
                    </h5>
                  <br/>
                  </Fragment>
                )}
                  <Videoplayer src={videoSrc} poster={poster} width='770' />
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </Fragment>,
      document.querySelector("#modal")
    );
}

export default Modal
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**What I actually wanna do is ( *`import videoSrc from '../FILES/{videoName}`*  something like this) import video by video name**

Is there any way to import such a way, or any other way I can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add those videos to your `public/` folder and then reference them from there. No import - just a string prop.

```
<Videoplayer src={'/FILES/1. Introduction.mp4'} poster={poster} width='770' />
```

Comment: It didn't work.

`VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported. 
Object { code: 4, message: "The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported." }`

**Throwing this error**

Comment: @NafizAlDin where did you put the files? This will be the same as hosting the files on a public server - if it doesn't work it's because it's not in a supported format

Comment: yea I found the problem!. there was something wrong with videojs. so I switched to react-player and it worked just fine..

Thanks man you were a great help.